# The Literature Meta has our logo graphic, and vice-versa

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As reported [on the Literature Meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216/why-does-our-meta-graphic-say-linguistics-instead-of-literature), the Literature Meta has our logo.  We have theirs:

[image: logo]

Looks like they got switched.  (Reposting here to hopefully spare some confusion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deployment.

Comment: I think we had the correct logo last night, but we lost it again :(